# cx_freeze TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have tried to fix this for two days:
setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [Executable("main.py",base="Win32GUI")]

setup(
    name="Life of Robert",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "An RPG with endless maps.",
    options={
    "build_exe":
            {
            "packages": ["pygame"],
            "include_files": ['Images/','Sounds/','Maps/','Houses/'],
            "includes": ["chest","gold","gui","message","player","settings","utils","wolf"],
            },

    },
    executables = executables

    )
```

Every time I run it with `python setup.py build` I get:
`TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`

You can find main.py at https://github.com/DrevanTonder/the-life-of-robert/blob/master/main.py

I have tried opening `main.py` in notepad++ and showing hidden symbols.
I can not find any `nul` or `\x00` symbols in the file

I am using python 3.4